# Can't bring text down to middle of div

Tags: html, css

Recently I have been trying to get used to floating divs and aligning them to fit all on one line. However, I have a small problem. In one of the codes I was creating, I noticed I could not get this text to go down at all.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/9sjyj0hy/

As you can see, the vs code is here:

```
<div class="fluidbox">vs.
```

and the end of the div is after all the other divs. The first way I tried to fix this was adding a line-height, well that only made things worse:

https://jsfiddle.net/9sjyj0hy/3/

As you can see, I edited the fluidbox to have a line-height of 100px, and the result made all divs drop down when I only need the VS text to do that. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text "vs" inside an element and position that element.

```
<span class="vs">vs.</span>

.vs {
    position : absolute;
    margin-top : 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work as you are saying. Have a look at the jsfiddle. The only thing you need to do is to wrap the vs in a span and add these css properties:

```
.fluidbox span {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/inzamamtahir/dcgmtnua/